# What's the difference between alternate key and Foreign key in database

Tags: sql

What's the difference between alternate key and Foreign key in database

Comment: Same as that between primary key and a foreign key. Alternate key is a combination of columns that _could_ be a primary key, but isn't. Alternate keys are a theoretical consideration, of interest only when designing a scheme; they play no role in your normal SQL use.

Answer (score 1):

*Alternate key* is unique key reminiscent of *primary key* that can be a column or the column's group of the table. Further, *alternate key* is unique all time in the table. Unlike the primary key, unique key is non-clustered index type as well as 
foreign key is to create a relationship with another table and it's used for data integrity.

```
|-------------------------------------|---------------------------------|
|**alternate key**                    |**foreign key**                  |
|-------------------------------------|---------------------------------|
|unique                               |non-unique                       |
|-------------------------------------|---------------------------------|
|never accept null value              |accept null value                |
|-------------------------------------|---------------------------------|
|can be multiple                      |can be multiple                  |
|-------------------------------------|---------------------------------|
|Independent another table            |Dependent another table          |
|-------------------------------------|---------------------------------|
|Create Noncluster index automatically|Cannot create index automatically|
|-------------------------------------|---------------------------------|
```

Comment: non-clustered index... Are you sure OP is using SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Alternate Key
All the keys which are not primary key are called an alternate key.

Foreign Key
A foreign key is a column which is added to create a relationship with another table. Foreign keys help us to maintain data integrity and also allows navigation between two different instances of an entity